# CRAFTER CMS build issue

Tags: content-management-system

I'm trying to  build CRAFTER CMS version(3.0.2-SNAPSHOT) using following command as instructed in its web site. I'm continuously getting build error after several minutes.

Build Command:
./gradlew init build deploy

Following is the stack trace which I'm getting:

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] Could not find the selected project in the reactor: !crafter-search-itest -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MavenExecutionException

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/data/CrafterRepo/craftercms/build.gradle' line: 781
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':build'.

  > [mvn, clean, install, -Dmaven.test.skip=true, -pl, !crafter-search-itest] @ ./src/search return a  non-zero value (1)
- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':build'.
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
  Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: [mvn, clean, install, -Dmaven.test.skip=true, -pl, !crafter-search-itest] @ ./src/search return a  non-zero value (1)
      at build_2aqvjygbxnaf64xrgv6yyjqsp.executeProcess(/data/CrafterRepo/craftercms/build.gradle:781)
      at build_2aqvjygbxnaf64xrgv6yyjqsp.executeProcess(/data/CrafterRepo/craftercms/build.gradle)
      at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:479)
      at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:191)
      at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript$ScriptDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BasicScript.java:130)
      at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.ConfigureDelegate.invokeMethod(ConfigureDelegate.java:80)
      at build_2aqvjygbxnaf64xrgv6yyjqsp$_buildModule_closure21.doCall(/data/CrafterRepo/craftercms/build.gradle:666)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
      at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:160)
      at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureSelf(ConfigureUtil.java:136)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.configure(AbstractTask.java:613)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.create(DefaultTaskContainer.java:143)
      at build_2aqvjygbxnaf64xrgv6yyjqsp.buildModule(/data/CrafterRepo/craftercms/build.gradle:659)
      at build_2aqvjygbxnaf64xrgv6yyjqsp.buildModule(/data/CrafterRepo/craftercms/build.gradle:636)
      at build_2aqvjygbxnaf64xrgv6yyjqsp$_run_closure10$_closure48$_closure49.doCall(/data/CrafterRepo/craftercms/build.gradle:380)
      at build_2aqvjygbxnaf64xrgv6yyjqsp$_run_closure10$_closure48.doCall(/data/CrafterRepo/craftercms/build.gradle:379)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:700)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:673)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
      ... 28 more
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 51s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, What's your maven version? (`mvn --version`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error indicates that you are not using the required version of maven (3.3.x or higher), please make sure that your version aligns with the one in the README.md in the CrafterCMS project https://github.com/craftercms/craftercms/blob/master/README.md